# Controlling vertical position of some text in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have two phrases of text in a div. The two phrases are vertically aligned in the middle of the div and they have different font sizes. I want the second phrase to be lower than its current position (a bit lower than the middle). How do I push the second phrase lower in the div without using javascript?

```
<div>
Phrase 1 - Phrase 2
</div
```

Comment: cant you add another div or span around the 2nd phrase with margin-top or padding-top styles ?

Comment: In your question title, surely you mean `vertical` instead of `horizontal`? You're talking about `lower` in your question.

Comment: @jujule: I can't use those if I am going to use a span or inline div for the phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div>
Phrase 1 - <span style="position:relative;top:4px;">Phrase 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/x5zpu/)

My demo may not be exactly how you've got it set up, but the idea should work:

- Set `position: relative` and `top: ?px` on the second phrase.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="phrase">
    Phrase 1 - <span class="p2">Phrase 2</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.phrase {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 40px
}
.p2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
Phrase 1 - <span id="phrase2">Phrase 2</span>
</div>
```

and CSS does wonders:

```
#phrase2 { position: relative; top: .2em; }
```